# h4, h5 expand and overflow when I zoom

Tags: html, css, overflow, web

Im working on some forms in [this website](http://www.sexitive.com.ar/se-una-consultora-sexitive/) and it renders perfectly fine but when I zoom in or out a little bit you can see how the h4's and h5's are no longer centered in the gray areas, sometimes even overflowing...I tried wrapping them with a div but still... Usually when I have had these kind of issues in the past it was because I had some wrapper's size set to a percentage... but I already checked that. Could somebody tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I ended up writing a wrapper for each h4 and applying a background to each of them, and hidden overflow to the wrapper. This seemed to solve the problem on all browsers. Then I just aligned the backgrounds so they looked like one long strip that crossed the screen. Thanks everyone for your comments and help

Comment: You should pick a correct answer or at least the one that lead you to fix your issue.

Comment: Making us write and spend our time then you answer to yourself and pick your own answer. Good to know so I won’t answer to any of your questions again.

Comment: you pushed me to choosing a correct answer and none of the answers that I got here were helpful. How come you're so upset about it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually for setups like that percentage values instead of pixels should be prefered, especially if you want to support browser zooming:

```
#mainContent {
    width: 100%;
}

div.catalogo-item {
    color: #506484;
    float: left;
    min-height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: Well I did that, but still get the same problem. I can't get it to stay still

Comment: I saw your problem in Firefox and by changing these values it dissappeared. What browser/version?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there is using absolute positioning for the **h4** and **h5** elements, which is totally dependant on the renderig pixel size result of the parent elements, that is why your layout breaks when text-zooming. Try not to position absolutely and prefer using text-align:center; to center these elements.

Don’t ever use absolute positioning for layout unless absolutely necessary, relying on absolute positioned layouts is the worst and you can expect future layout breaks.

Comment: I changed it already but it still moves. I'm pretty lost

Comment: Tell me in what way I must zoom to be able to reproduce this.